# How to make sure that object property of property exist simple?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Is there a way to get rid of this type of checks for objects:

```
reader && reader.firstProp && readerSecondProp && readerThirdProp && doSomething
```

Object looks like this:

```
const reader = {firstProp :{readerSecondProp:{readerThirdProp: 'yeeee'}}}
```

or

```
const reader = {}
```

I want to somewthing like this

```
proporyExist(readerThirdProp) && do something
```

Comment: [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: i need simple check, without much of code.

Comment: You can you some external libraries if you don't want to write your own implementation. get from lodash will serve your purpose here. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get